# Reportviewer and RDLC line break issue with records

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

Wonder if anyone can help. I have a c# web application that uses the Reportviewer control that uses RDLC files to create the reports.

The problem that I'm having is that any fields in the database that have a line break in them look like this on the report

458%20Kingshighway%0ALynnwood%0A0081%0ASouth%20Africa

Does anyone know what is going wrong? Is it something to do with encoding of the HTML?

Thanks,
Airlok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the "vbcrlf" function apply line breaks on the report